# parent to child soql not working

Tags: soql, childrelationship, parent, child-to-parent

i am at a wits end, any help greatly appreciated

I have a child object named acf_address__c , that is a child of the contact object

the child relationship name on the acf_address__c is called Constituent_Addresses

I run the following query, and always get the contact id, name and null for my child subquery, i believe i have it correct, and know that data exists for both the parent and the child of this contact Id

```
select id , name
,(SELECT Name, MailingStreet__c FROM Constituent_Addresses__r)
from contact
 WHERE Id  = '0030R00000OsKCjQAN';
```

( i did not name any objects, dealing with aftermath of contracted work)

Comment: How are you checking the contents of the subquery? Please include the code you're using.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham ah, thanks for the tip, razorsql doesnt know how to render the lookup, so it shows null, nothing wrong with my query after executing in dev console , doh

Answer (score 0):

If you use subquery and debug it shows only Parent record.
 you also run our SOQL query in Query Editor Here it shows the child and Both Record 
 you use following query dev console then show both Record

```
 List<Contact> conList =[select Id,Name,(SELECT Name, MailingStreet__c FROM Constituent_Addresses__r) from Contact WHERE Id ='0030R00000OsKCjQAN';

 List<Constituent_Addresse__c> acfAddress = conList[0].Constituent_Addresses__r;
 System.debug('List of Address'+acfAddress);
```